# How to select the last cell from table which is not null, using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, null, html-table, tr

I have a table with following rows and cells:

```html
<table id='table1'>
  <tr id='row1'>
    <th>index</th>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id='row2' name='row'>
    <td name='index'>1</td>
    <td name='product'>Apples</td>
    <td name='description'>fruits</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='row3' name='row'>
    <td name='index'>2</td>
    <td name='product'>Bananas</td>
    <td name='description'>fruits</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='row4' name='row'>
    <td name='index'>3</td>
    <td name='product'>Carrots</td>
    <td name='description'>vegetables</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='row5' name='row'>
    <td name='index'></td>
    <td name='product'></td>
    <td name='description'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need to select the value for the last `td` with name='index' which is not null. Anyone has any idea how can this be done.

Comment: Just FYI, your HTML is invalid. There's no `<row>` element available.

Comment: Sorry about that. I just fixed it.

Comment: @RabiaRanaKhan: Will the `td` that you want always be in the last `tr`? In other words, if the index in `row5` is not empty but in `row4` it is, should it give you the one from `row4`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following selector :

```
$('td[name=index]:not(:empty):last')
```

Comment: My apologies, I skipped it and just read "not using jQuery." I'll pay more attention in future :)

Comment: You missread the title i think  ZeroBased_IX, I read it as not null, using jquery

Comment: Just be careful of whitespace if using this approach. A `td` with just a newline character will match `:not(:empty)`.

Answer (score 2):

For purely educational purposes, here is a non jQuery version:

```
function getLastNonEmptyCell(tableSelector) {
  //Find parent table by selector
  var table = document.querySelector(tableSelector)
  //Return null if we can't find the table
  if(!table){
    return null;
  }
  var cells = table.querySelectorAll("td")
  var lastNonEmptyCell = null;
  //Iterate each cell in the table
  //We can just overwrite lastNonEmptyCell since it's a synchronous operation and the return value will be the lowest item in the DOM
  cells.forEach(function(cell) {
    //!! is used so it's so if it is not null, undefined, "", 0, false
    //This could be changed so it's just cell.innerText.trim() !== ""
    if (!!cell.innerText) {
      lastNonEmptyCell = cell;
    }
  })

  return lastNonEmptyCell;
}

var cell = getLastNonEmptyCell("#table1")
```

**Edit**

As @squint suggested this can be done much more succintly:

```
function lastNonEmptyCell(tableSelector) {
  //Since we want the last cell that has content, we get the last-child where it's not empty. This returns the last row.
  var row = document.querySelectorAll(tableSelector + " td:not(:empty):last-child")
  //Just grabbing the last cell using the index
  return row[row.length - 1]
}
```

Comment: Good to see non-jQuery versions, but you're not taking advantage of the selector engine to the extent possible. Why not `document.querySelectorAll("#table1 td:not(:empty)")`, and then just grab the last result?

Comment: That's a better one-line approach. Good job @squint

Comment: That doesn't work out-of-the box, since that will return all `td` that aren't empty. Had to do `:last-child` which returned the last row.

Comment: That's what I meant by *"then just grab the last result"*. I did though forget that the OP wanted the `name` to be `index`, so I should have typed `"#table1 td[name=index]:not(:empty)"`. The `:last-child` will cause this to fail. Since the OP didn't say that the element must be the last child of its parent, you wouldn't want that on there either way.

Comment: Good call :) @squint

Comment: Though perhaps the OP actually wants to limit this to the last `tr`. Hard to say. If that's the case, then putting `tr:last-child` in the middle would be good.